# Lubuntu-Desktop not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, lubuntu, software-installation, login, lxde

I recently decided to install LXDE on my Ubuntu 14.04 (it's not a fresh installation, however it's quite recent). I wanted to use mainly Unity and use LXDE sometimes when I needed higher performance.
Following a guide to do this, I used:

```
sudo apt-get lubuntu-desktop
```

for getting the Lubuntu flavor. After everything finished I shutdown the computer, for some reason. To my surprise, the shutdown screen as well as the boot one has the Lubuntu logo instead of the Ubuntu one. A minor annoyance as it was nowhere written this would be one of the effects.
Then, contrary to what I was made to believe, the login screen is the Lubuntu one. I couldn't find any way to choose the desktop environment from there so I just log in. After I login I see that the desktop is still Unity. To sum up: my LXDE installation made my Ubuntu *believe* it was Lubuntu, but left the only aspect I installed it for unsolved.
After this *experience*, I decided to uninstall it using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove lxde
sudo apt-get autoremove lubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get --purge remove lxde
sudo apt-get --purge remove lubuntu-desktop
```

The last two were not necessary, apparently. These operations left the situation unchanged. It also appears that the Lubuntu login screen just covers up the Ubuntu one as for a brief second it appeared after logging in.
So my questions are:

1. if and how can I reset my system to its former state, and
2. can I then install LXDE with the ability to choose between the DEs and hopefully be able to use the programs from Unity on LXDE (ideally without installing its own software again)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is unity desktop working normally?

Comment: @Learner Yes. Everything but the login screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Synaptic and search 'Lubuntu' and mark for complete removal.

In Synaptic remove `lxdm` (login manager for lxde) and also check if following packages are installed : `unity-greeter` and `lightdm`. Install them if they are not.
if you prefer terminal-

```
sudo apt-get remove lxdm
sudo apt-get install unity-greeter
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

also:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

You'll enter a greeter configuration file. There find the line

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

if the line does not exist, add it.

Just install 'LXDE' instead of `lubuntu-desktop`. It works the same, but won't show on startup.

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I uninstalled everything related to Lubuntu. lxdm was not installed and unity-greeter and lightdm were already. Unfortunately, it did not work (although the artwork was gone and the boot is normal, so there's that). I additionally tried: removing everything related to lxde (I suspected lxlauncher was actually the problem), and reinstalled unity-greeter and everything related to lightdm. The login screen is still the same, just no background. By mistake, I didn't mark anything for complete removal, just removal. What to do now?